# Sticky top not working on HTTPS site, only HTTP?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I have built a website using a Bootstrap 5 template, and the sticky top works for on the HTTP version, but not the HTTPS.

Has anyone else had this problem? And solved it?

Comment: Please edit your post and include an example code (MCVE) and a more concrete explanation of "not working".

Comment: Maybe you are trying to load your Bootstrap or any other relevant resource from a non-https-location. Insecure content gets blocked in modern browsers when the page is hosted on a secure context. Please show the HTML that loads the template resources (js/css). If that is the case, the network tab in your browser's developer tools will show you that.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It didn't have the sticky-top bit on the nav class.

Not sure why it worked on the http version though!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in my project but I solved it by adding jquery CDN [link](https://code.jquery.com/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).